# What's would be a good algorithm (in words) of how to solve #8 in Project Euler with Lua?

Tags: algorithm, lua, splice

This is the question:

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

In lua, what would be the best way, loop or no loop, to splice and return the 900 hundred something 13 digits in a number, string, or array? (I will just use recursion to find the product of those 13 digits)

Please don't return the answer to the actual problem.

Comment: This question appears to be too broad. Try something yourself, and if it's not working, post some specific code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think an easy way to do this that doesn't require any splicing or additional storage is this :

1. Multiply the first 13 digits. You can use `sub` to extract those digits from positions in the string, and `tonumber` to convert them to number to multiply. Let's say we call the result `product`.
2. Go through positions pos = 14 to 1000 and recalculate `product` as `product / number-from-position-pos-13 * number-from-position-pos`. Compare it with the largest product seen so far and remember position if it's the largest one.
3. Return position.

Since the sequence may include zeroes, they may require a separate handling. Instead of multiplying by zero, you can keep track of how many zeroes the current sequence has and don't update the largest number if the number of zeroes in the sequence is more than zero. When you have zero in position `pos-13`, you decrease the number of zeros and when you have zero in position `pos`, you increase the zero counter.

Comment: Without looking at Euler#8 to see if it is clarified in the question, you might need to add a check-for-zero to your algorithm incase the 1000-digit number could include 0's